# How can I save the output of a timer and use it elsewhere?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have the following:

```
private void mainClock_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    timeSecond++;
    if(timeSecond >= 60)
    {
        timeMinute++;
        timeSecond = 0;
        if (timeMinute >= 60)
        {
            timeHour++;
            timeMinute = 0;
        }
    }

    displayTime();

}

public void displayTime()
{
    labelTimerDisplay.Text = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}", timeHour, timeMinute, timeSecond);
}

public string theTime()
{
    return labelTimerDisplay.Text;
}
```

Whenever I call `theTime()` it returns as `00:00:00` no matter how long the timer has been running. `displayTime()` works as expected but if I call `displayTime()` anywhere else, it also returns as `00:00:00`.

How do I make it so that I can call `theTime()` and get the actual time the timer ran for?

Comment: Is `mainClock_Tick()` been called? You got to hook it up.

Comment: why not this : `return String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}", timeHour, timeMinute, timeSecond);` from `theTime()`

Comment: Without a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces your problem, it's impossible to say what's wrong. Maybe you just didn't start the timer. That said, your code is broken, because it (apparently) depends on the timer tick occurring every second, precisely. Which it won't. You need to keep separate the timer (which can deal with updating the display) and the actual elapsed time calculation. Use `Stopwatch` or `DateTime.UtcNow` for the latter, computing elapsed time directly instead of keeping three different counters.

Comment: As @QualityCatalyst mentions, could you show us the code where you add the `mainClock_Tick` tick event to the timer?

Comment: @Travis N where have you declared timesecond ,timehour,timeminute

Comment: @PeterDuniho, I am going to try `Stopwatch`, that may be what I need. In one of my buttons, I have `mainClock.Start();` which starts the timer. I think you're right. The more I've looked into timers, I need that second one. I think that might be the problem I am having. Thanks!